# Sending message with image

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

Is there any way to use MFMessageComposeViewController or any other controller that may be out there to send a message with an image?

MFMessageComposeViewController apparently does not support that but someone may developed some kind of hack out there...

any way? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy your image programmatically to the clipboard, then let the user paste the image in Message Composer View,

```
[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].image = yourImage;
```

Comment: I thought about that but was wondering if there's something more... 

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577565/how-to-attach-image-with-message-via-iphone-application