# Attach image to message composer in ios 6

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

How to attach an image to native message composer in ios6? I want to implement the same sharing via message function we can see in default photos app.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577565/how-to-attach-image-with-message-via-iphone-application

Answer (score 4):

For Mail:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];            
NSData *exportData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pic ,1.0);
[mailController addAttachmentData:exportData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"Photo.jpeg"];
[self presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES];
```

The only way is through email currently. Unless you want to create a own MMS gateway to allow your app to support MMS..

For Message:

After reading up, instead of using MFMessageComposeViewController,you could UIApplication sharedApplication.

Example:

```
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
pasteboard.persistent = YES;
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pic ,1.0);
pasteboard.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

NSString *phoneToCall = @"sms: 123-456-7890";
NSString *phoneToCallEncoded = [phoneToCall stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:phoneToCallEncoded];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Longpress and click on Paste and message will be pasted...

Hope this helps... pic refers to the UIImage you are passing...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What is the "mailController"? is it MFMessageComposer or Email composer?

Comment: `MFMailComposeViewController *mailController` .. it is declared in the first line.

Comment: MFMessageComposeViewController does not have such a method [messageCo addAttachmentData:exportData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"Photo.jpeg"];

Comment: @sajaz The MFMessageComposeViewController can not add attachment to the body. It only accepts NSString for the body. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MFMessageComposeViewController/body

Comment: @verbumdei Thanks for the comment. That means we cannot share an image via iMessage from an app? Currently its only possible through iphone's default photos app?

Comment: @sajaz currently there is no public API for adding attachment for the message. There is suggestion to use sms url schema as mentioned in the possible duplicate question I linked above. You can try that.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  NSMutableDictionary * attachment = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [attachment setObject: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image,0.5) forKey:@"attachmentData"];
        [attachment setObject: @"productImage.jpeg" forKey:@"attachmentFileName"];
        [attachment setObject: @"jpeg" forKey:@"attachmentFileMimeType"];


        NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [params setObject: @"subject" forKey:@"subject"];
        [params setObject: @"matterText" forKey:@"matterText"];
        [params setObject: [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:attachment, nil] forKey:@"attachments"];

}







#pragma mark - Sharing Via Email Related Methods

-(void)emailInfo:(NSMutableDictionary*)info
{    
    if (![MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Email Configuration"
                              message:@"We cannot send an email right now because your device's email account is not configured. Please configure an email account from your device's Settings, and try again."
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }

    MFMailComposeViewController *emailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    emailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    NSString * subject = [info objectForKey:@"subject"];
    NSString * matterText = [info objectForKey:@"matterText"];

    if(subject)
        [emailer setSubject:subject];

    if(matterText)
        [emailer setMessageBody:matterText isHTML:NO];

    NSMutableArray   * attachments = [info objectForKey:@"attachments"];

    if (attachments)
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < attachments.count ; i++)
        {
            NSMutableDictionary  * attachment = [attachments objectAtIndex:i];

            NSData   * attachmentData = [attachment objectForKey:@"attachmentData"];
            NSString * attachmentFileName = [attachment objectForKey:@"attachmentFileName"];
            NSString * attachmentFileMimeType = [attachment objectForKey:@"attachmentFileMimeType"];

            [emailer addAttachmentData:attachmentData mimeType:attachmentFileMimeType fileName:attachmentFileName];
        }
    }

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        emailer.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
    }

    [self.navigationController.topViewController presentViewController:emailer animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: I want to share via message composer NOT the email composer

Answer (score 0):

I think you cant attach an image in the message composer. It is only possible in mail composer.

Comment: Then how can we share images via iMessage on ios5 upwards?

Comment: i tried a lot on this subject for my app. but i didn't find any solution. Anyway, you can continue searching. i only expressed my thoughts

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts, Lets see