# MFMessageComposeViewController no visibe interface for presentModalViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, presentmodalviewcontroller, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to send an sms programmatically but I get the error no visible interface for presentModalViewController:completion: . The same code works with presentViewController but I need to display the sms dialog as a modal so it will return to my app. Any idea what I am missing ?

```
- (void) sendSMS:(NSString*)txtMsg photo:(UIImage*)image
{
    if (![MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {

        UIAlertView *alertV = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Your device not support SMS" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertV show];
        return;
   }

    MFMessageComposeViewController *mVC = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];

   mVC.body = txtMsg;
   mVC.messageComposeDelegate = self;

    if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendAttachments]) {
        NSLog(@"ok");
    }

    [mVC addAttachmentData: UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)   typeIdentifier:@"public.data" filename:@"image.png"];

    // This gives a compilation error
    [self presentModalViewController:mVC animated:YES completion:nil];

    // This compiles but gives the wrong behavior
    // [self presentViewController:mVC animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: Check with this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27573491/3378413

Comment: That post does not open it as a modal so when you hit send it doesn't call the delegate to close and return to the app. That is why I am asking specifically about presentModalViewController